# Can "will + have + participle" be used in questions?

Tags: grammar

I know that when I want to tell somebody that I will have something done in the future with a specified time I can say:

> I will have finished doing my work by 2p.m. tomorrow.

My question is, can this pattern be used in questions?

> Will you have finished your work by 2p.m. tomorrow?/Will you have finished doing your work by 2p.m. tomorrow?

Are the above sentences correct?

Answer (score 2):

*Absolutely correct!*

The *future perfect* can be used in that way for forming a question.

> Will you have finished your work by tomorrow?

[More is here on BBC.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/intermediate/unit-30/tab/grammar)

There's an example as well:

> *Will you have finished the report by this afternoon?*

---

*I would avoid using 'doing' work.*